# How Can I Assign Multiple People to a Single Account

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a dataset with multiple accounts, periods, products etc. Similar to the below except with 300k rows of data with new accounts being added all the time.

```
Period AccountID AccountName Sales
Q1     A2        Account1    103.15
Q1     B5        Account2    85.14
Q2     A2        Account1    184.59
Q3     C9        Account3    93.21
```

In the past I've used the a table like this to create a relationship between the *Account ID* and the *Account Managers*. This effectively creates 3 unique options when looking at a Slicer/Filter.

```
AccountID AccountManager
A2        Tim/Jim
B5        Jim
C9        Tim
```

I'm unable to use the below as I know that PowerPivot doesn't support Many-to-Many relationships like this. Likewise, If i create another table that links just the *Account ID* in my data to the below it does not filter the measures/values when put into a Pivot Table.

```
AccountID AccountManager
A2        Tim
A2        Jim
B5        Jim
C9        Tim
```

Is there anyway to create this relationship that would reduce the unique options in a Slicer/Filter but keep the functionality where the same account can appear under 2 names?

Comment: Create a "Dimension" table of Account and use it as a link between your Account/Period table and your second table (AccountID/AccountManager) with the 4 rows.

Comment: @mxix I'm assuming you mean something like this: 

`A2/

B5/

C9`?

In the pivot table i'm using my original dataset to supply the Account IDs and names as they can be added/changed at any time from the feed. So when I try create a table like that with the 2 relationships, it isn't changing the data when the slicers/filter is changed

Comment: It seems that you are using Excel as a database. A pivot table isn't the holy grail for everything. Why don't you use a real database? If you invest some time in learning SQL and use a proper database, it makes life so much easier. Money cannot be the problem: There are even good free databases out there.

Comment: @ffonz unfortunately there are work constraints that unfortunately wouldn't make SQL option even if I did have the knowledge.